# Read a table file to arrays in C

Tags: c

In Matlab is one command, but I need to write some simple function in C (or C++ actually, but it doesn't matter). My goal now is to create three "double" arrays, that are taken form a table file.
The file looks like this (QEOS.txt):

```
T rho P
11.605 2.51188643150958e-13 4.28547303990553e-16
11.605 3.16227766016838e-13 4.28547303990553e-16
11.605 3.98107170553497e-13 4.28547303990553e-16
11.605 5.01187233627271e-13 4.28547303990553e-16
11.605 6.30957344480194e-13 4.28547303990553e-16
11.605 7.94328234724282e-13 4.28547303990553e-16
11.605 1e-12 4.28547303990553e-16
11.605 1.25892541179417e-12 4.28547303990553e-16
14.6098294038713 2.51188643150958e-13 5.45304484892599e-16
14.6098294038713 3.16227766016838e-13 5.45304484892599e-16
14.6098294038713 3.98107170553497e-13 5.45304484892599e-16
14.6098294038713 5.01187233627271e-13 5.45304484892599e-16
14.6098294038713 6.30957344480194e-13 5.45304484892599e-16
...........
```

And I want the first column to become a variable "T", the second to be "rho" and the third "P". Shouldn't be hard at all, right?
So I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
struct threeNum{
    double n1, n2, n3;
};
 
int main(){
    int n;
    struct threeNum num;
    double P,T,rho;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("QEOS.txt","r");
     for(n = 1; n < 25; ++n){
         fread(&num, sizeof(struct threeNum), 1, fptr);
         printf("n1: %f \tn2: %f \tn3: %f  \n", num.n1, num.n2, num.n3);
     }
     fclose(fptr);
     
     T=num.n1;
     rho=num.n2;
     P=num.n3;
     return 0;
}
```

The "25" is just ab example. In any case, the code prints 0.000's and random garbage. What's wrong?
P.S:
And I get *"*** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated Aborted (core dumped)"*

Comment: Instead of `fread`, you want `fscanf`. `fread` is for reading binary data and not for formatted input, while your input file seems to be a text file. Also, always check the return value of `fopen` before performing any file operation.

Comment: C vs C++ really does matter.  If you are writing C++, you should not be using `fopen/fread/fclose` at all.  Use the idioms of the language.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki
I changed to:
 fscanf(fptr, "%lf %lf %lf", num.n1, num.n2, num.n3);
 But I get a warning:" format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’"

Comment: William Pursell,
The compiler of C++ is able to run C, no? It seems like C functions are a way more simple and intuitive for this task.

Comment: "The compiler of C++ is able to run C, no?" No.

Comment: @MichaelL.  `fscanf(fptr, "%lf %lf %lf", &num.n1, &num.n2, &num.n3);` You need to pass addresses of the targets, not values of the targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you must use text based functions like [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), as opposed to binary ones such as [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread), when reading formatted text.

You should always test the return values of library functions as most of them can fail with dramatic results (program crashes or misleading output).

Note that

```
T=num.n1;
rho=num.n2;
P=num.n3;
```

has no effect in this program.

---

Suggestion: use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more control, reading line by line.

A quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    double P, T, rho;
    FILE *fp = fopen("QEOS.txt", "r");

    if (!fp) {
        perror("fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char line[512];

    if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) || !strstr(line, "T rho P")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid or missing header.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        if (3 == sscanf(line, "%lf%lf%lf", &T, &rho, &P)) {
            printf("n1: %f\tn2: %e\tn3: %e\n", T, rho, P);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```